# Question: Can you perform contains operations on a global variable of type list in Drools

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine, business-rules

i was wondering if i can perform a contains operation on the left hand side (LHS) on a drools rule.
Something of the sort:

```
global java.util.List myGlobalList;

dialect  "mvel"

rule "checker"
    when
    Task() from myGlobalList
    then
    System.out.println(myGlobalList);
end
```

The example above is not a working one and im not quite sure how to make it work. I am open to suggestions with other keywords from drools (contains, exists, in)!

Answer (score 1):

Only if you want to check the global's initial state. Generally, globals are out of scope of what the rule is aware of. Your rules won't be cognizant of any changes to the the global.

You should instead put your series of tasks in a list in working memory like this:

```
rule "checker"
when
    $myTasks: List() // suggest not a raw list in working memory, but this "works"
    Task() from $myTasks
then
    System.out.println($myTasks);
end
```

Your rule, as-is, will only work if `Task` is present in your global list at the time the rules are fired. If a rule subsequently removes the task, that won't be visible. There's also some additional weirdness around visibility that I don't fully understand myself because you shouldn't be writing rules against globals anyway.

In theory, if you understand the Drools lifecycle -- especially how the matcher phase works and how you can re-trigger that phase based on actions in your rules (`update`, `insert`, etc.) -- you chould in theory write rules like this that key off of the global. But since the global isn't part of working memory, it can't be a party to those same actions (eg you can't call `update(myGlobalList)`). This also adds a lot of complexity because future maintainers of your rules will need the same understanding of the lifecycle ... it'll become a maintenance nightmare, basically.

At the end of the day, you really shouldn't be using globals at all. They're usually a code smell more than anything, it's how we used to get data out of the rules back in the "old days" (10 plus years ago), because there weren't really any better ways and we didn't know any better. They're really analogous to 'static' variables in Java -- if you've got multiple threads, you can't rely on the value in a static non-volatile variable in 'if' conditions.

So the answer to your question is -- technically yes, but practically no. Don't do it. Design your rules better.

---

Note that the [Drools documentation](https://docs.drools.org/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-globals-con_drl-rules) warns you not to do this as well:

> Do not use global variables to establish conditions in rules unless a global variable has a constant immutable value. Global variables are not inserted into the working memory of the Drools engine, so the Drools engine cannot track value changes of variables.
>
> Do not use global variables to share data between rules. Rules always reason and react to the working memory state, so if you want to pass data from rule to rule, assert the data as facts into the working memory of the Drools engine.

---

Basically the only time you'd ever reference a global on the left hand side ("when") is when the global is acting as a constant. So something like this:

```
global Float freeShippingMinimum;

rule "Free shipping if minimum met"
when
  $c: Cart( subtotal >= freeShippingMinimum,
            shippingFee > 0.0 )
then
  modify( $c ) {
    setShippingFee( 0.0 )
  }
end
```

In this example, you get free shipping if your subtotal meets a minimum threshold. That threshold is passed into the rules because it is a constant and it comes from some external data source. It's passed into the rules as a global because it is a constant; since it *is* a constant, we can refer to it on the left hand side / "when".

Comment: Thanks for the extensive information on the topic, however now when i execute the rule i have 10 elements in the list and one task that is equal to one of those 10 elements, however it gets executed 10 times, because the print statement is present 10 times.

Comment: Yes? That's the initial state, that's how it works. Don't use globals on the left hand side.